# capturing stderr and stdout from an already running process in solaris

Tags: process, solaris, stdout, stderr

I've got a process that is currently running (arserverd) that was started by user "remedy".  I am able to log in as this user.  I would like to capture stderr and stdout without restarting the process.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

If the process is already running, you could use the `truss` command to intercept writes to file descriptor 1 or 2:

```
truss -w 1,2 -p pid_of_arserverd
```

Truss will output lines like

```
write(1, " m e s s a g e\n", 8)                     = 8
```

Truss is specific to Solaris. On linux systems, look for `strace` instead.

Truss will slow down the process that you're trussing somewhat, so it's not something you'd want to use all the time. If you're looking for a permanent solution, your best bet is probably to redirect stdout and stderr to a file when launching the program. You can regularly truncate the file to keep its size manageable. An alternate is to run the program within a `screen` session that you can reconnect to when you want to interact with the program.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so but you can try to read from `/proc/PID/fd/1` for stdout and `/proc/PID/fd/2` for stderr (replace `PID` with the PID of the process).